# ACF loop within category loop - Wordpress

Tags: php, wordpress, advanced-custom-fields

I cannot get my posts to display on a category page.

It finds if the posts are within and category and displays content fine.. But the loop I am using does not bring in the posts.. Any help would be great.

```
<?php if (is_category(array(4, 5, 6))) { ?>
    <?php if (have_posts()) : while ($the_query->have_posts()) : $the_query->the_post(); ?>
        <div class="case-study-box">
            <a href="<?php the_permalink(); ?>">
                <div class="post-img ripple-me" style="background-image: url(<?php the_field('thumbnail_image'); ?>)">
                </div>
            </a>
            <div class="post-intro">

                <span><?php the_category(' '); ?></span>
                <a href="<?php the_permalink(); ?>"><?php the_title('<h4>', '</h4>'); ?></a>
                <a href="<?php the_permalink(); ?>">Read more</a>
            </div>
        </div>
        <!--Close .case-study-box -->
    <?php endwhile; else: ?>
    <?php endif; ?>
<?php } else { ?>
```

Comment: Does is not display anything? how is the HTML coming up?

Comment: Nothing at all... Just shows as blank

Comment: where is your query? also i guess it should be "$the_query->have_posts()" and not just have_posts() on line 2